# Manipulate data in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am trying to pull a number from a database and use it in a view. In the database the number is usually 2500 or 1000, or something similar. I want to divide this number by 1000 to get 0.25 or 0.1, which is a more accurate representation of 'percentage'.

In an mvc model, how do I set the value to itself divided by 1000?

I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets percentage.
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Percentage
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Percentage / 100);
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Probably you will need to another ReadOnly property, with logic you need. Something like `DisplayPercentage`

Comment: `Doesn't seem to work` is rather undescriptive.

Comment: Also, you and @user972 need to brush up on your math skills.

Comment: Not one of my best moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Uriil says, you need to have extra property that will be using the percentage value to produce manipulated value.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets actual percentage.
/// </summary>
public decimal DisplayPercentage
{
    get
    {
        return (this.Percentage / 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Otherwise you need to have a MAPPING defined and in that mapping you can specify this logic:

    CreateMap<yourDTO, yourModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Percentage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Percentage/100));